# Generating pdf error, although work fine on github, not in localhost

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, mozilla

So I have been working on card generating form html to pdf.
I finally got my hands on a github project made by mozilla people
[Mozilla Kerala](https://github.com/MozillaKerala/Card-Generator)

It runs ok on their given link. But, when i download it in my localhost i get something like this. when i click generate card.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'ID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1302
>
> Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 1302

This is the line in source code of cssmgr.php.

```
    1297    $classes = array();
    1298    if (isset($attr['CLASS'])) {
    1299     $classes = preg_split('/\s+/', $attr['CLASS']);
    1300    }
    1301    if (!isset($attr['ID'])) {
    1302         $attr['ID'] = '';
    1303        }
```

Kindly, let me know if there any tweak to be done.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this issue on PHP 7.1 by adding

```
$attr = is_array($attr) ? $attr : [];
```

to the /mpdf60/classes/cssmgr.php **on Line No. 1296**.

Comment: No working, I am getting an error:

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Card-Generator-master\vendor\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 30642

Comment: @Hamad Rakshani just upgrade your mpdf.php file from this link ===> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baselbers/mpdf/5cbaff4303604247f698afc6b13a51987a58f5bc/mpdf.php

Comment: This what shows up now :/Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Card-Generator-master\vendor\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 17074

Comment: i think your mpdf version was older, try to Upgrade from this Link (Download mpdf.V6.1.0) ===> https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/releases

Comment: Nope, same error: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\Card-Generator-master\vendor\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 17074